# Installing KVM for Asp.Net VNext

Tags: kvm, asp.net-core

I want to play with the new aspnet vnext, but it needs kvm to be installed.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/version-manager) they say that i need to clone the repo and run `kvmsetup.cmd`. BUT there is no such file when i clone the repo.

So i went back to their [home page](https://github.com/aspnet/Home), i cloned the repo (home), now i can see a `kvmsetup.cmd` file. when i run it in the powershell it doesnt install KVM !!

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**
i had this problem :

[image]

I resolved this problem by opening the powershell as an administrator with the following command : `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.

It did work, but it didn't add KVM to the path :

[image]

Comment: More information would be helpful. Does the kvmsetup.cmd succeed or fail? If it fails is there an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing kvm outside of the cloned directory.

Comment: 2 things to remember : 
- change the execution policy.
- dont execute inside the cloned diretory as dave said

Answer (score 3):

This has changed now. Just open command prompt with admin rights and run this to install KVM.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvminstall.ps1'))"
```

That will download KVM and set all the corrects paths. Unrestricted wont work if you don't run CMD with Admin rights.

Close the command prompt and reopen command prompt to start using KVM